# How to make dropdownlist from the DataTable not outside your table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have dropdownlist but its outside my DataTable and needs to be inside, but i am struggling to achieve this and see my code below for logic. Please help me to improve this logic for user readability. The reason for this logic that i want my dropdownlist it should allow user the option to select from the given data not data being exposed outside this record list, i hope i am making sense as exactly to what i am aiming to achieve.

```
 // Drop downlist for WhoAttended.

    public enum Attendees
    {
        Engineers,
        Technicians,
        Inspectors
    }

// View cshtml

<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/dataTables.semanticui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section scripts{

      <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.semanticui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#EventsManagementsTable").DataTable({

                "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "5%", "targets": [0] }, 
                { "className": "text-center custom-middle-align" ,"targets":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
                ],

                "serverSide": "true",
                "order":[0,"asc"], 
                "processing": "true",
                "language": {
                    "processing": "processing...... please wait"
                },
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Dashboard/GetData",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "JSON"

                },
                "columns": [
                    {"data": "TrainingType", "name": "TrainingType"},
                    { "data": "TrainingDescription", "name": "TrainingDescription"},
                    { "data": "Price", "name": "Price"},
                    { "data": "Venue", "name": "Venue"},
                    { "data": "Facilitator", "name":"Facilitator" },
                    { "data": "WhoAttend", "name" : "WhoAttend" },
                    {"data": "RSVP", "name":"RSVP" },
                ]


            });

        });







    </script>
```

// What i am doing currently to get dropdownlist on DataTable.

```
 <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#EventsManagementsTable").DataTable({

                "columnDefs": [
                { "width": "5%", "targets": [0] }, 
                { "className": "text-center custom-middle-align" ,"targets":[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] },
                ],

                "serverSide": "true",
                "order":[0,"asc"], 
                "processing": "true",
                "language": {
                    "processing": "processing...... please wait"
                },
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/Dashboard/GetData",
                    "type": "POST",
                    "datatype": "JSON",

                },

                "columns": [
                    {"data": "TrainingType", "name": "TrainingType"},
                    { "data": "TrainingDescription", "name": "TrainingDescription"},
                    { "data": "Price", "name": "Price"},
                    { "data": "Venue", "name": "Venue"},
                    { "data": "Facilitator", "name":"Facilitator" },
                    { "data": "WhoAttend", "name" : "WhoAttend" },
                    { "data": "RSVP", "name": "RSVP" },

                    "columns":[
                    {

                        "data": "WhoAttend",
                        "name": "WhoAttend",
                        "render": function (value) {
                            return $("<select/>")
                                .addClass("form-control")
                                .attr("name", "WhoAttend")
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Engineers"))
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Inspectors"))
                                .append($("<option/>").text("Technicians"))
                                .val(value)
                                .html();
                        }

                    }


                ],

                ]

            });

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi in your columns section add this code to add a custom HTML element:

```
"columns": [
                {"data": "TrainingType", "name": "TrainingType"},
                { "data": "TrainingDescription", "name": "TrainingDescription"},
                { "data": "Price", "name": "Price"},
                { "data": "Venue", "name": "Venue"},
                { "data": "Facilitator", "name":"Facilitator" },
                { "data": "WhoAttend", "name" : "WhoAttend" },
                {"data": "RSVP", "name":"RSVP" }
                   {
                className: "center",
                defaultContent:`<select name='slcCustom' class='custom' >
                  <option value='default'>select something</option>
                  <option value='1'>Apple</option>
                  </select>`
              }
               ]
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8k5vcox/2/) you can check.

Hope it helps

Comment: i am using my example i am getting this error line 92 TypeError: n[m] is undefined

Comment: the column when i use className creates a bug to my side and dont know why.

Comment: @Luks10Mkontwana can you include a working jsffidle of your code ?